# how to display more than 40 characters in one line of LCD?

Tags: arduino, avr, lcd

I am using JHD 162A LCD module, and I want to print a string which is 48 characters long. I am using the scroll command for the LCD, but the remaining 8 characters are being displayed on the 2nd line. What can I do to print them on first line?

Comment: What code have you tried? Do you have a link to a datasheet for the "JHD 162A LCD module"?

Answer (score 1):

Get a good understanding how the RAM in your LCD display LSI chip is organized and which RAM location refers to which display position.

Also - the scroll command acts across the whole display memory (see data sheet). If you want to scroll only 1 line (or parts thereof) ==> software

Try a [44780 simulator](http://www.geocities.com/dinceraydin/djlcdsim/djlcdsim.html) ... (and some [further reading](http://www.geocities.com/dinceraydin/lcd/commands.htm))